# Deeply updating React state (array) without Immutable, any disadvantages?

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

I know using Immutable is a great way to deeply update React state, but I was wondering if there are any drawbacks I'm not seeing with this approach:

Assuming `this.state.members` has the shape `Array<MemberType>` where `MemberType` is `{ userId: String, role: String }`.

If the user changes a user's role, the following method is executed:

```
  changeMemberRole = (userId, event, key, value) => {
    const memberIndex = _findIndex(this.state.members,
      (member) => member.userId === userId);

    if (memberIndex >= 0) {
      const newMembers = [...this.state.members];

      newMembers[memberIndex].role = value;
      this.setState({ members: newMembers });
    }
  };
```

Would there be any advantage to replacing this with Immutable's `setIn`, other than potentially more terse syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between using or not `Immutable.js` is, of course, immutability¹ :)

When you declare `const newMembers = [...this.state.members]` you're copying an array of references, this is indeed a new array (modifying a direct child by index like `0`,`1`,`2` is not reflected) but filled with the same object references, so inner/deep changes are shared. This is called **a shallow copy**.

#### `newMembers` are not so *new*

Therefore any changes to any `newMembers` element are also made in the corresponding `this.state.members` element. This is fine for your example, no real advantages so far.

#### So, why immutability?

Its true benefits are not easily observed in small snippets because it's more about the mindset. Taken from the [Immutable.js homepage](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/):

> Much of what makes application development difficult is tracking
>   mutation and maintaining state. Developing with immutable data
>   encourages you to think differently about how data flows through your
>   application.

Immutability brings many of the functional paradigm benefits such as avoiding side effects or race conditions since you think of variables as values instead of objects, making it easier to understand their scope and lifecycle and thus [minimizing bugs](https://medium.com/@jackmahoney/using-mutable-data-with-react-flux-cd202f09da18#.1e52y0u82).

One specific advantage for react is to [safely check for state changes in `shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html) while when mutating:

```js
// assume this.props.value is { foo: 'bar' }
// assume nextProps.value is { foo: 'bar' },
// but this reference is different to this.props.value
this.props.value !== nextProps.value; // true
```

When working with objects instead of values `nextProps` and `this.props.value` will be considered distinct references (unless we perform a deep comparison) and trigger a re-render, which at scale could be really expensive.

¹*Unless you're simulating your own immutability, for what I trust `Immutable.js` better*

Comment: Thanks! Though I want to point out that if you do `x = [...y]`, it is *not* a reference, but a copy. You can verify this yourself in the Chrome console.

Comment: @ffxsam not a deep copy! Check with an array of objects like your example and I'll update my answer as that's the very confusion you want to avoid

Comment: @ffxsam actually now that you said that you can appreciate the Immutable strongest asset: its interface which saves you from falling into that kind of confusion and introducing bugs

Comment: Oh shoot, you're exactly right! My apologies. I could've sworn using the spread operator flattens the array and does a clone. http://i.imgur.com/HDw4ZfO.png Whoever upvoted my comment should take that away! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not copying role, thus if one of your components taking the role as prop (if any) cannot take benefit of pure render optimization (overriding shouldComponentUpdate and detecting whenever props have been actually changed).

But since you can make a copy of the role without immutablejs, there is no any effective difference except that you have to type more (and thus having more opportunities to make a mistake). Which itself is a huge drawback reducing your productivity.

Answer (score -1):

From the `setIn` docs:

> Returns a new Map having set value at this keyPath. If any keys in keyPath do not exist, a new immutable Map will be created at that key.

This is probably not what you are looking for since you may not want to insert a new member with the given role if it does not exist already. This comes down to whether you are able to control the `userId` argument passed in the function and verify whether it exists beforehand.

This solution is fine. You can replace it with [update](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/update) instead, if you want to.

Comment: This is no advantage, his approach is not immutable so I think the question deserves a more abstract and complete answer (see mine)

Comment: `This is no advantage.`

I have clearly mentioned: This solution is fine. He wanted a comparison with `setIn`. Your answer doesn't mention this anywhere.

Comment: Of course it does: his approach mutates state whereas immutable.js not, he's shallowly copying the array and the nested object is shared between both. I'd suggest you to remove the downvote from it.

Comment: `const newMembers = [...this.state.members]` this statement makes a new copy. How are the `members` and `newMembers` referencing the same object?

Comment: it makes a **shallow** copy, in his example @ffxsam has an array of objects, this is an array of references: the spread notation will create a new array with the same references, see: http://imgur.com/F0IHLNN

Comment: Can you suggest why this behavior is not shown [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=let%20a%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%3B%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20%5B...a%5D%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(%27before%20a%3A%27%2C%20a)%3B%0Aconsole.log(%27before%20b%3A%27%2C%20b)%3B%0A%0Aa.push(4)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(%27after%20a%3A%27%2C%20a)%3B%0Aconsole.log(%27after%20b%3A%27%2C%20b)%3B).

Comment: because there you have an array of primitive values: `1`, `2` and `3` are not referenes but values so they are copied, whereas objects are copied by reference. This is a common behavior in many languages as it saves lots of memory by not copying complex data structures

Comment: Alright. Sorry to bother you. I want to take my downvote back but SO doesn't allow now. Thanks for the info. Really sorry to bother you.